# Prevent back press ModalBottomSheet in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I'm using material3:1.2.0-beta01, and I want my ModalBottomSheet to not be swipeable by the user or dismissable if the user does a back press.

I tried adding an empty BackHandler in the ModalBottomSheet Composable, but it doesn't work.

Can you please help?

That's my code:

```
var showBottomSheet by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
if (showBottomSheet) {
    BackHandler {}
    ModalBottomSheet(onDismissRequest = { }, sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 12.dp),
        dragHandle = null,
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.errorContainer) {
        BackHandler {}
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp) {
            Column {
                // content
                // when clicking on a bouton, we launch a coroutine to hide the sheet
                // and in invokeOnCompletion, we pass showBottomSheet to false 
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue, but it's marked as fixed, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278216859

Comment: isn't there a `confirmStateChange` in the `rememberModalBottomSheetState `?

Comment: Not in the one I'm using: there are only skipPartiallyExpanded and confirmValueChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass argument for the **properties** parameter to the ModalBottomSheet.

It goes like:

```
if (openBottomSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { openBottomSheet = false },
            sheetState = bottomSheetState,
            properties = ModalBottomSheetProperties(
                isFocusable = true,
                securePolicy = SecureFlagPolicy.SecureOn,
                shouldDismissOnBackPress = false
            )               
        ) { ... }
```

And, for not being swipeable, I guess you want to show whole content. For this, use

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true) // this is the state passed to the ModalBottomSheet
```